# Hiding edit text in onCreate, but then not storing values once values entered for EditText, clipEx has text data false

Tags: android, text, android-edittext

The app crashes when the button is selected which uses the values converted from edit texts. Tried multiple ways to move the part edittext = R.ids .. to try and make sure the edittexts picks new values after the oncreate first runs.

Think the calculation part causes the crash because its trying to perform a calculation with stored values from the edit text when the value is false from the first time the edit text gets the R.ids... in the onCreate method.

needed hide/display editText based off a radio button setonCheckedChangeListener in the onCreate method. So edittext = R.ids .. set in this method, the app does not crash at runtime like it would if I moved the edittext = R.ids .. to the testFunction method.

```
EditText editTextValue;
EditText editTextValue2;
double amount; 
protected void onCreate(){...
//Get edittext field parameters
 editTextValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_weight_kg);

 //listener to switch editTexts on which radio button selected in units group
   unitsRG.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
             if (checkedId == R.id.imperial) {
                editTextValue2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editTextValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

 void testFunction(View view){
     String stringValue = editTextValue..getText().toString();

    //check value as long as its not empty for the edit text , save it 

    if (editTextValue.getText().length() > 0) {
        amount = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
        Log.e("MainActivity", " " + amount);
    }

}
```

but now when I run the app I get this error in the long cat 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmHZB.png)

```
E/ClipboardServiceEx﹕ clipEx is android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@1f70b420
E/ClipboardServiceEx﹕ clipEx has text data : false
```

here is the xml for one of the edit texts

```
<EditText
         android:id="@+id/editText_weight_lb"
         style="@style/EditTextViewStyle"
         android:visibility="visible"/>
```

In the editTextStyle , I set the textCursorDrawable to null to try and have different colors for the pointer and underline colors. Not sure if this could also be affecting the editTextView storing the value

```
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
```

I also tried setting edittext = R.ids in the testfunction and in the onCreate method. See if the editTexts would store the values the user enters rather than keeping the empty values when onCreate initially run.

I still got the same clipEx has text data:false error after trying this.

I searched the logcat error "clipEx has text data: false" and found something regarding samsung memory leaks. 
https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/133 
I am using a samsung galaxy for testing. I feel the issue is more with where I'm setting the edittexts to the R.ids thats causing the issue.

I saw the post for checking to make sure valid value entered for edittext. 
[Issue with empty EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11383755/issue-with-empty-edittext)
[How to Check whether a value is entered in editexts before submitting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28584033/how-to-check-whether-a-value-is-entered-in-editexts-before-submitting)
will add the check after finding out why values are not getting stored/ still remaining false. 
Thanks

Comment: getWeightEnteredlb  ? ?what this variable? weightEnteredkg is your edittetx?

Comment: modified variables to reflect what type they are now

Answer (score 1):

well I tried a different approach to implement the method.

I placed a button in the OnCreate method to define the event handlers against the buttons:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button calculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.calculate);
    calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        String stringValue = editTextValue.getText().toString();

        //check value as long as its not empty for the edit text , save it 

        if (editTextValue.getText().length() > 0) {
            amount = Integer.parseInt(stringValue);
            Log.e("MainActivity", " " + amount);
          }
         ..... 
         .....
  }
}
```

By using the button method in the OnCreate, when I ran the app, errors would actually come up on the Integer.parseInt() method call. Turns out that even though the editTexts that I was entering text for did not have text values, the other editTexts still had strings for the text, so this would cause the app to crash.

```
<EditText...
android:text="kg"/>
```

I took out the text values. It worked again.

I also took out this line in the style sheet for the editText. This was to change the editText border color, cursor color, or line.

```
<item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@null</item>
```

I tried the public void testFunction() approach which I had used before, the app works, but the clipEx has text data : false continues to show up.

But the app works now with either the Button method in onCreate or as a public void testFunction() approach.